# Creation of multiple named pipes

Tags: c, fork, mkfifo

I am trying to make a program that makes a number of children defined by the user. The parent must use named pipes (it is a requirement) to send information back and forth with his children. So, I need to create a number of named pipes equal to the amount of children I am forking. How can I do this efficiently and have every child know what his pipe is named?

```
pid_t childpid;
for(i = 0; i < numWorker; i++){
    // char *pipeName = "somename";
    // change the pipeName to reflect the child by adding a suffix
    // mkfifo(pipeName, 0666);
    childpid = fork();
    if(childpid < 0){
        perror("fork\n");
    }
    else if(childpid == 0){
        signal(SIGCONT, handleSignalChild);
        // how can I open the fifo here and then carry on reading and writing 
        //inside the while() below?
        break; // child exits the creation loop.
    }
}


// Main program execution begins here
while(1){

    if(childpid == 0){
        // read and write to the already opened pipes.
        //code to handle child execution.
    }
    else{
        // open all fifo pipes and get ready to read and write stuff.
        //code to handle parent execution.
    }

}
```

**EDIT**: Reworded the question to make more sense.

Comment: Why use named pipes instead of normal pipes? And I don't understand the rest your requirements.

Comment: I feel like your current example would probably be cleaner using normal pipes. Still, you should make named pipes in the parent, and tell each child the name of the pipe they should use

Comment: It is not important. Anyone could create them, even another process, but *both* need to open it (which needs them to know the name of the pipe(s))

Comment: @melpomene I know that normal pipes would be cleaner and easier but it is a requirement for some odd reason (yes this is homework, not mine but homework nonetheless).

Comment: @wildplasser so when I create my pipes how can I know that each child gets one pipe and does not interact with an others child pipe?
Could you provide an example?